# update mysql data through django

Tags: python, django

I have read the django tutorial, bit can't understand how to update a mysql record in django. My model and code is show below. I'm trying to update all values which are entered by user in form.

```
class PatientInfo(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    uhid = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    age = models.IntegerField()
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

UPDATE CODE:

```
patient_edit = PatientInfo.objects.get(id__exact=patient_id)
PatientInfo.objects.filter(address=patient)update(patient_edit)
```

Comment: Formatted the post a bit... What field are you trying to update?  What have you tried.  Also, you try to do a filter on `PatientInfo` based on the `address` field, but that doesn't exist in your model definition.

Answer (score 3):

see the docs at - http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#saving-changes-to-objects

If you wanted to change the name of a patient_edit

```
patient_edit = PatientInfo.objects.get(id=patient_id) # object to update
patient_edit.name = 'New name' # update name
patient_edit.save() # save object
```

or basic form docs at - http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method